# Is there any url length limit CardService.newOpenLink().setUrl()

Tags: gmail-addons

I want open new link using ResponseBuilder But I got weird error I know URL length limit is upto 2,083 characters. But my URL just 780 characters long is there any limitation in URL length or any?

[Error from gmail add-on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Nlw.png)

Comment: Is your url defined in your urlFetchWhitelist array in the manifest? See here for more info: https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/manifests#whitelisting_urls

Comment: It's already there 

`"openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
      "https://calendar.google.com"
 ]` .It works fine if i reduce length of `&details` get parameter

Comment: Each prefix must have a non-empty path. For example, `https://www.google.com/` is valid but `https://www.google.com` is not. From the docs - https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/manifests#whitelisting_urls - Looks like you are missing a trailing slash.

Comment: Sorry I missed the reduce the length and it works, I have no idea if there is a max length. I tried searching but cant find anything.

Comment: Actually im trying to open `https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=EventName&dates=20131206T050000Z/20131208T060000Z&location=EventLocation&sprop=name%3aName&sprop=website%3aEventWebite&details=EventDetail&sf=true&output=xml` with my custom `details` parameters problem is value longer 700 characters. If i open link in chrome it'll work but my gmail addon not allowing it.

Comment: Anyway thank you for you're comments

Comment: Good luck, I hope you solve it soon.